# Pair Correlations in R with mixed types in Data Frames

Tags: r, correlation

If my data frame has mixed types in it (continuous and categorical), and I want to compute pair correlations using, for instance, `pairs` in R, is there a way to quickly only select the numerical type columns from the frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emulate this solution as applied to a data frame `X`:

```
pairs(subset(X, select=sapply(X, is.numeric)))
```

Note that `pairs` will fail when `X` has fewer than two numeric columns, so for general-purpose use, consider encapsulating this in a function that checks the result of `sapply` before doing the subsetting.